# Pass JSON to JSP from action class without using Ajax in struts

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, jsp, struts

In the JSP, I am able to get the JSON from action class using the code below. Can someone please tell me if there is a way to receive the response (JSON) from action class without using Ajax?

```
$.ajax({
url:"/StrutsExample1/helloWorld.do",
data:params,
type: "post",
dataType:"json",
success:function(response){
          $.each(response,function(i){  
              $.each(response[i],function(key,value){
                 $('#info').html(key+" "+value);})
           })
},
    error:  function(e){ alert("fail " + e);}                   
})
```

UPDATE:

The following code is used in the action class.

```
response.setContentType("text/json; charset=utf-8");
JSONObject json = createJsonObject();  //to construct the JSON
PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
out.print(json);
out.flush();
return mapping.findForward("success");
```

In struts-config.xml, I have the following in the action mapping:

```
<action path="/helloWorld" type="test.action.HelloWorldAction" name="helloWorldForm">
<forward name="success" path="/index.jsp" />
```

Then, in JSP file, instead of using Ajax call as above, it looks like:

```
$(function(response){
   $.each(response,function(i){ 
              $.each(response[i],function(key,value){
                 $('#info').html(key+" "+value);})
           })
})
```

However, the key and value are undefined on execution. JSON was constructed properly in the action class. Please help to point out how to get the JSON passed to jsp.

Answer (score -1):

Yes. you can do in a normal way. By submitting the page, you can reach the action class and set your response as

```
response.setContentType("application/json");
```

Comment: This do not answer how to get response content (like a json string) in the jsp, without using ajax. Let's say I have no form to submit. Just a forwarding from the Action to jsp, with text (in the response) to be shown/parsed (the json string)